# How to identify a category and print from a dictionary

Tags: python

New to the world of python, I am trying to get a list of of categories in this dictionary a list of `'type'` and `'sub-type'`.

I have tried a few different things but no luck, any help would be appreciated

```
{'accounts': [{'account_id': 'JqRQG4WVV7IMe3LDG7Ebc97Kjoel4asdrRjqX',
   'balances': {'available': 100,
    'current': 110,
    'iso_currency_code': 'USD',
    'limit': None,
    'unofficial_currency_code': None},
   'mask': '0000',
   'name': 'Plaid Checking',
   'official_name': 'Plaid Gold Standard 0% Interest Checking',
   'subtype': 'checking',
   'type': 'depository'},
```

Comment: What is your expected output?
Your question is unclear
Also, why have a dictionary with one key? instead of a dictionary which has a list of sictionaries just have a list of dictionaries

Comment: Oh sorry about that - it's a download from Plaid via API - the question is I am trying to basically get a nice list of all the different 'types' and 'sub-types' of transactions that occurred.  The dictionary is basically what was downloaded.  I hope that makes things more clear

Comment: Please add a short and concise code snippet that shows what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the accounts and collect the types and subtypes:

```
for subdict in original_dictionary['accounts']:
     print('{}:{}'.format(subdict['type'], subdict['subtype']))
```

If you have to look for types and subtypes in values corresponding to other keys besides the 'accounts' key, you'll have to iterate through the key value pairs of your original dictionary via something like:

`for key, value in original_dictionary.items():`